# Rally Java Rest API 302 Temporarily Moved Error

Tags: rally

I am creating a integration tool for TeamCity to Rally and using the Java REST API. When I try to create an object of type "build" I get an exception thrown by the restAPI with a 302 "temporarily moved" error.

How do I handle this? I cannot see any settings in the Rally RestAPI that turns on or off redirects and the API is not handling the redirect.

Any suggestions?

Here is the code that is being issued. The create call to the restAPI throws an exception. The two calls to **def.getWorkspace().getRef** and **def.getRef()** return the URLs for the workspace and build definition entries which this build record is associated with (the string is the **"_ref"** attribute from those entities).

```
try {
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
    obj.addProperty("workspace", def.getWorkspace().getRef());
    obj.addProperty("buildDefinition",def.getRef());
    obj.addProperty("duration",1.05);
    obj.addProperty("message", "Message for the build");
    obj.addProperty("number","TEST0000");
    obj.addProperty("start", isoFormat.format(new Date()));
    obj.addProperty("status","Passed");
    obj.addProperty("uri", "http://teamcity.com");

    CreateRequest request = new CreateRequest("build", obj);
    request.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID,Name"));
    CreateResponse response = restAPI.create(request);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Could not create object of type: " + type, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you successfully been able to create other objects/artifacts? Do you know if you have a Proxy server? It's possible that the 302 is coming from an intermediate Proxy rather than Rally. If you have a proxy, you can do:

`restAPI.setProxy("https://myproxy","myproxyuser","myproxypassword");`

To setup a proxy for your REST connection. Aside from that, a couple of comments:

1. Valid values for "Status" are [SUCCESS, FAILURE, INCOMPLETE, UNKNOWN, NO BUILDS]
2. There's no need to do a setFetch on a CreateRequest - the Fetch parameter is only used for Queries.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mark, no I am not going via a Proxy and I have now tried to create a Defect using the Java API and I get the same error. I can query objects fine but can't seem to create any objects.

Comment: Perhaps try running my working example located here: https://gist.github.com/markwilliams970/0ee60296d012757db2f1. Also, please eliminate the setFetch on your createRequest - it's not needed and is invalid REST syntax. Also make sure you set a valid value on Status. "Passed" is not a valid value. It must be one of the items in the array listed in Comment (1) in my answer above. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Mark, found the issue. I was using http:// instead of https:// and the queries worked fine against the http:// connection but I could not create objects unless I changed it to https://

Comment: Thanks for the update - glad to hear you got it working. I'll do some additional testing - if I can reproduce the issue, this would seem to be a bug in Rally REST. You should get a re-direct to https in all aspects of Create/Read/Update/Delete, not just on Creates.

Comment: Thanks Mark, the redirect does work in the .net REST API Library and this is what threw me as my previous development in C# was accessing http:// and worked fine.

Comment: And as a FYI I now have a TeamCity to Rally integrator working whcih I will shortly publish to GitHub for anyone else. Nice to see a big GREEN Build Success message on my Rally page!